# Cosmid genomic library, or genomic cosmid library?

Tags: genetics, terminology

Which usage is better for referring to a "cosmid library of genomic DNA fragments"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used Cosmid Library but Cosmid Genomic Library is better than Genomic Cosmid Library.

Comment: Indeed - comments are better for statements of opinion. In answers, please try to provide reasoning why one phrasing might be better than another.